# How to rollback OracleDB commit with Camel Jms Transaction rollback

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, apache-camel, jms

I am using Apache camel 3.1.0 with Spring boot 1.5.6 and I have successfully created perfectly working Camel's Transactional routes. Basic route is like this

```
from(Source JmsEndpoint)
.process(
myDaoImplClass.myTransactionalDatabaseMethod("Save data coming in Message")
).to(Destination Endpoint)
```

Issue occurs when Queue Depth gets full on destination queue and due to transactional route it is not removed from Source queue. Thus source queue again sends same message and my database method gives DataIntegrityViolationException due to duplicate message.

Is there a way I can rollback persisted data or do commit only when whole route is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Camels onCompletion and the Unit of Work](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/oncompletion.html) concept.

You can use it to do stuff on failure or success only.